# Javascript age gate not working on Chrome, fine in Firefox, IE, Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to fix/redesign a website, and I can't possibly find out what's wrong. It's an age gate, with three inputs for day(dia) month(mes) and year(anyo) and a send button (#btn_entrar). It works perfectly on Firefox, Safari and Explorer, but in Chrome, when the user enters an age < 18 it just ignores everything and loads #page2, instead of showing the alert. I''ve been reading and I think it might be the .click(function() part, but I just can't figure it out (I'm just learning javascript). Here's the code:

```
$('#btn_entrar').click(function() { 
    var dia=("0" + $("#dia").val()).slice (-2);
    var mes=("0" + $("#mes").val()).slice (-2); 
    var anyo=("000" + $("#anyo").val()).slice (-4);

    var fecha_nac=dia+'/'+mes+'/'+anyo;
    var curr = new Date();

    var txtVal = mes+'/'+dia+'/'+anyo;

    if (anyo<1900) { alert("Fecha no válida."); exit(); }       
    if (isDate(txtVal)==false) { alert("Fecha no válida."); exit(); }

    curr.setFullYear(curr.getFullYear() - 18);
    var dob = Date.parse(fecha_nac);

    if((curr-dob)<0)
    {
        alert("Se requiere tener más de 18 años para acceder a la web.");
}
    else
    {   
        $('#page1').delay(0).fadeOut(1500);         

        // Cargar pagina 2
        $('#page2').delay(1300).fadeIn(1500);
        $('#cabecera').delay(1000).fadeIn(1500);  // mostrar avioneta       
    } 
});
```

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check chrome console for any errors? Anyways Can you create a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: What is `exit()` also the string day/month/year will not work as you expect.

Comment: No chrome errors. It's up on my test server at http://casadelpixel.com/mangaroca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a locale issue. Instead of using `Date.Parse()`, try using something like

```
anyo = int.Parse(anyo, 10);
mes = int.Parse(mes, 10);
dia = int.Parse(dia, 10);
var dob = new Date(anyo, mes - 1, dia);
```

instead.

Note the `mes - 1`, the `Date(year, month, day)` constructor numbers months from 0 - 11, not 1 - 12!